# Set date when saving bitmap

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I am using this function to save my Bitmap.

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
view.getDrawingCache(), "image.png", "image");
```

The bitmap is saved successfully, but the date on the image is 1.1.1970.

How do I make the current date?

Comment: `the date on the image` ? What do you mean? File time? Exif time? Mmmm png has no exif...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not set the date with `MediaStore.Images.Media` you need to use this.

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Media.TITLE, title);
values.put(Media.DESCRIPTION, description); 
values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis()); // DATE HERE
values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, filepath);

context.getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

If you need any other pointers, I would take a look at [MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/provider/MediaStore.java#L888)

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard `MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage()` method and then update datetime manually:

```
public void insertInMediaStore(Bitmap bitmap, String title, 
            String description,  ContentResolver contentResolver) {

    // insert to media store
    String photoUriStr = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(
            contentResolver, 
            bitmap, 
            title , 
            description);
    Uri photoUri = Uri.parse(photoUriStr);

    // add datetime
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, now);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_MODIFIED, now);
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, now);
    contentResolver.update(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
            values, 
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?", 
            new String [] { ContentUris.parseId(photoUri) + "" });

    // call media scanner to refresh gallery
    Intent scanFileIntent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, photoUri);
    MyApp.getInstance().sendBroadcast(scanFileIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

MediaStore's insertImage adds the image to the store and creates/updates a ImageColumns record.

This record includes a **DATE_ADDED field, which is the one you are looking for.**

It also contains a DATE_TAKEN field which has nothing to do with add time. It denotes, well, the date 
in which the image was taken and is almost always taken from within the image (more accurately: from 
its EXIF data) and therefor **not changed when an old image is added to the store**.

I suspect your problem comes from reading the prior instead of the latter,  as you should.
To retrieve this field for all images:

```
String[] projection = new String[]{
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED // <-----------------
    };

    Uri images = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    Cursor cur = managedQuery(images, projection,  "",  null, "");
```

You will probably want to filter for one (or few) specific images.

BTW 1.1.1970 indicates "could not find the taken-date inside image", which should not happen for a 
photo taken on a modern device.

Answer (score 1):

Can confirm that on a 4.1.2 device the Gallery app shows 1970 for the jpg too. But a file explorer shows the file time which is correct. So probably the Gallery app extracts Exif info.

On a KitKat 4.4.2 device the Gallery app shows the correct date. The file time as indicated by a file explorer is also coorrect.

I was amazed that pictures got saved in ../DCIM/Camera.

But anyhow the jpg always carries the file time as the file name IS the file time. Those pictures are saved as `1405427951171.jpg` which translates a 15-07-2014 ...... and 1405427951171 is nummer of milli seconds after 1970.

Answer (score 1):

Adding info to [this answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24758538/2819864) what worked for me was adding not only `DATE_TAKEN`, but also `DATE_ADDED`:

```
values.put(Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000); // should be in unit of seconds
values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis()); // should be in unit of ms
```

I took that code [from a comment here](https://gist.github.com/samkirton/0242ba81d7ca00b475b9) and used it like this:

```
public void addLastPhotoToGallery(String photoPath) {
    if (!Strings.isNullOrEmpty(photoPath)) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        // Add the date meta data to ensure the image is added at the front of the gallery
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, System.currentTimeMillis());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, photoPath);

        getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File photoFile = new File(photoPath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
}
```